# server.HiveServer2: Error starting priviledge synchonizer

Tags: authentication, hive, kerberos

Hive version 3.1.2
Hadoop components(hdfs/yarn/historyjob) with kerberos authentication.

hive kerberos config:

```
hive.server2.authentication=KERBEROS

hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal=hiveserver2/_HOST@BDP.COM

hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.keytab=/etc/kerberos/hadoop/hiveserver2.bdp-05.keytab

hive.metastore.sasl.enabled=true

hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file=/etc/kerberos/hadoop/metastore.bdp-05.keytab

hive.metastore.kerberos.principal=metastore/_HOST@BDP.COM
```

First, start the Metastore:
./bin/hive --service metastore > /dev/null &

Nothing unnormal in the log.

Then start hiveserver2 :
./bin/hive --service hiveserver2 > /dev/null &

Here is the start logs :

```
2020-12-30T11:28:48,746  INFO [main] server.HiveServer2: Starting HiveServer2
2020-12-30T11:28:49,168  INFO [main] security.UserGroupInformation: Login successful for user hiveserver2/bigdata-server-05@BDP.COM using keytab file /etc/kerberos/hadoop/hiveserver2.bdp-05.keytab
2020-12-30T11:28:49,171  INFO [main] cli.CLIService: SPNego httpUGI not created, spNegoPrincipal: , ketabFile:
2020-12-30T11:28:49,187  INFO [main] SessionState: Hive Session ID = 0754b9bc-f2f9-4d4c-ab95-a7359764bc49
2020-12-30T11:28:50,052  INFO [main] session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/hiveserver2/0754b9bc-f2f9-4d4c-ab95-a7359764bc49
2020-12-30T11:28:50,066  INFO [main] session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/hive/0754b9bc-f2f9-4d4c-ab95-a7359764bc49
2020-12-30T11:28:50,069  INFO [main] session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/hiveserver2/0754b9bc-f2f9-4d4c-ab95-a7359764bc49/_tmp_space.db
2020-12-30T11:28:50,600  INFO [main] metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://bigdata-server-05:9083
2020-12-30T11:28:50,605  INFO [main] metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient: HMSC::open(): Could not find delegation token. Creating KERBEROS-based thrift connection.
2020-12-30T11:28:50,653  INFO [main] metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient: Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
2020-12-30T11:28:50,653  INFO [main] metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient: Connected to metastore.
2020-12-30T11:28:50,654  INFO [main] metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient: RetryingMetaStoreClient proxy=class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient ugi=hiveserver2/bigdata-server-05@BDP.COM (auth:KERBEROS) retries=1 delay=1 lifetime=0
2020-12-30T11:28:50,781  INFO [main] service.CompositeService: Operation log root directory is created: /tmp/hive/operation_logs
2020-12-30T11:28:50,783  INFO [main] service.CompositeService: HiveServer2: Background operation thread pool size: 100
2020-12-30T11:28:50,783  INFO [main] service.CompositeService: HiveServer2: Background operation thread wait queue size: 100
2020-12-30T11:28:50,783  INFO [main] service.CompositeService: HiveServer2: Background operation thread keepalive time: 10 seconds
2020-12-30T11:28:50,784  INFO [main] service.CompositeService: Connections limit are user: 0 ipaddress: 0 user-ipaddress: 0
2020-12-30T11:28:50,787  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:OperationManager is inited.
2020-12-30T11:28:50,787  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:SessionManager is inited.
2020-12-30T11:28:50,787  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:CLIService is inited.
2020-12-30T11:28:50,787  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is inited.
2020-12-30T11:28:50,787  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:HiveServer2 is inited.
2020-12-30T11:28:50,835  INFO [pool-7-thread-1] SessionState: Hive Session ID = 693b0399-aabd-42b5-a4b2-a4cebbd325d4
2020-12-30T11:28:50,838  INFO [main] results.QueryResultsCache: Initializing query results cache at /tmp/hive/_resultscache_
2020-12-30T11:28:50,844  INFO [pool-7-thread-1] session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/hiveserver2/693b0399-aabd-42b5-a4b2-a4cebbd325d4
2020-12-30T11:28:50,844  INFO [main] results.QueryResultsCache: Query results cache: cacheDirectory /tmp/hive/_resultscache_/results-23ae949b-6894-4a17-8141-0eacf5fe5a63, maxCacheSize 2147483648, maxEntrySize 10485760, maxEntryLifetime 3600000
2020-12-30T11:28:50,846  INFO [pool-7-thread-1] session.SessionState: Created local directory: /tmp/hive/693b0399-aabd-42b5-a4b2-a4cebbd325d4
2020-12-30T11:28:50,849  INFO [pool-7-thread-1] session.SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/hiveserver2/693b0399-aabd-42b5-a4b2-a4cebbd325d4/_tmp_space.db
2020-12-30T11:28:50,861  INFO [main] events.NotificationEventPoll: Initializing lastCheckedEventId to 0
2020-12-30T11:28:50,862  INFO [main] server.HiveServer2: Starting Web UI on port 10002
2020-12-30T11:28:50,885  INFO [pool-7-thread-1] metadata.HiveMaterializedViewsRegistry: Materialized views registry has been initialized
2020-12-30T11:28:50,894  INFO [main] util.log: Logging initialized @4380ms
2020-12-30T11:28:51,009  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:OperationManager is started.
2020-12-30T11:28:51,009  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:SessionManager is started.
2020-12-30T11:28:51,010  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:CLIService is started.
2020-12-30T11:28:51,010  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is started.
2020-12-30T11:28:51,013  WARN [main] security.HadoopThriftAuthBridge: Client-facing principal not set. Using server-side setting: hiveserver2/_HOST@BDP.COM
2020-12-30T11:28:51,013  INFO [main] security.HadoopThriftAuthBridge: Logging in via CLIENT based principal
2020-12-30T11:28:51,019  INFO [main] security.UserGroupInformation: Login successful for user hiveserver2/bigdata-server-05@BDP.COM using keytab file /etc/kerberos/hadoop/hiveserver2.bdp-05.keytab
2020-12-30T11:28:51,019  INFO [main] security.HadoopThriftAuthBridge: Logging in via SERVER based principal
2020-12-30T11:28:51,023  INFO [main] security.UserGroupInformation: Login successful for user hiveserver2/bigdata-server-05@BDP.COM using keytab file /etc/kerberos/hadoop/hiveserver2.bdp-05.keytab
2020-12-30T11:28:51,030  INFO [main] delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2020-12-30T11:28:51,033  INFO [main] security.TokenStoreDelegationTokenSecretManager: New master key with key id=0
2020-12-30T11:28:51,034  INFO [Thread[Thread-8,5,main]] security.TokenStoreDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2020-12-30T11:28:51,035  INFO [Thread[Thread-8,5,main]] delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2020-12-30T11:28:51,035  INFO [Thread[Thread-8,5,main]] security.TokenStoreDelegationTokenSecretManager: New master key with key id=1
2020-12-30T11:28:51,040  INFO [main] thrift.ThriftCLIService: Starting ThriftBinaryCLIService on port 10000 with 5...500 worker threads
2020-12-30T11:28:51,040  INFO [main] service.AbstractService: Service:HiveServer2 is started.
2020-12-30T11:28:51,041 ERROR [main] server.HiveServer2: Error starting priviledge synchonizer:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.startPrivilegeSynchonizer(HiveServer2.java:985) ~[hive-service-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.start(HiveServer2.java:726) [hive-service-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.startHiveServer2(HiveServer2.java:1037) [hive-service-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.access$1600(HiveServer2.java:140) [hive-service-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2$StartOptionExecutor.execute(HiveServer2.java:1305) [hive-service-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.main(HiveServer2.java:1149) [hive-service-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318) [hadoop-common-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232) [hadoop-common-3.1.3.jar:?]
2020-12-30T11:28:51,044  INFO [main] server.HiveServer2: Shutting down HiveServer2
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the hiveserver2-sit.xml was created by Apache Ranger when turning the ranger-hive-plugin on. Once I disable the ranger-hive-plugin, hiveserver2-sit.xml was edited by Ranger.

Here are the remaining configurations:

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.security.authorization.manager</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.DefaultHiveAuthorizationProvider</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.security.authenticator.manager</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultAuthenticator</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.conf.restricted.list</name>
        <value>hive.security.authorization.enabled,hive.security.authorization.manager,hive.security.authenticator.manager</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Start hiveServer2 will encounter the previous exception.

Remove hiveserver2-site.xml will work fine.

I don't know why? Somebody can explain?

Answer (score 0):

is this still actual ? , if yes , check logs . You should see that it tries to connect to zookeeper , if not described it will try to connect to localhost:2181 , so either it must be there or zk quorum servers should be described.